# Nondegenerate curve on surface scroll

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $C\subset X\subset \mathbb{P}^r$ is an irreducible *nondegenerate* curve on a rational normal surface scroll $X$, why is $h^1(\mathscr{O}_X(C\ ))=0$?

reference: *The dimension of the Chow variety of curves* (Eisenbud and Harris) page 293

Comment: Is the scroll linearly normal?  The effective cone of a linearly normal surface scroll is quite simple.  Except if the surface scroll is abstractly $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$, there is one ray that is spanned by an irreducible curve with negative self-intersection (the "directrix"), but the span of that curve is strictly smaller than the span of the surface scroll.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it doesn't look to me like the paper assumes $X$ is linearly normal. I did look up the effective cone before asking this question, but I think a LES shows that $h^1$ can be nonzero if we choose $C$ to be the directrix and $X$ such that $C^2\leq -2$, so the nondegenerate hypothesis needs to be used somehow.

Comment: The point is, if the directrix has self-intersection $-e$, then you need to add $e$ fibers to the directrix to get a linearly nondegenerate curve.  For this class $C$, $h^1(\Sigma,\mathcal{O}(C))$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference and to save others trouble, I think we can proceed as follows.

From the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X(C )\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_C(C )\rightarrow 0$, we get $0=H^1(\mathscr{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(\mathscr{O}_X(C ))\rightarrow H^1(\mathscr{O}_C(C ))\rightarrow H^2(\mathscr{O}_X)=0$, so we need to check $H^1(\mathscr{O}_C(C ))=0$.

It suffices to see $C\cdot C>2g_a(C )-2\Leftrightarrow K_X\cdot C<0$. Since $K_X=-2D+(-e-2)F$, where $D$ and $F$ are the directrix and the fiber of the projection $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ respectively, it suffices to show $D\cdot C>0$.

Here we use nondegeneracy of $C$ to see $C\neq D$ and irreducibility of $C$ to see $C\cdot D>0$.

Comment: Please note: adding $m\geq e$ fibers to the directrix class, i.e., forming the class $C=D+mF$, is both what is needed for existence of an irreducible curve in the linear system $|C|$ and for vanishing of $h^0(\Sigma,\mathcal{O}(A-C))$ for an ample divisor class $A$, i.e., the image of $C$ is linearly nondegenerate under the embedding given by $|A|$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful remark. I'm sorry to be clueless, but I see why $m\geq e$ is necessary, but why is it sufficient for the existence of an irreducible curve in $|C|$? Also, about $C$ being linearly nondegenerate, are you saying for some choice of $A$ or for all choices of $A$? If $|A|$ takes fibers to lines and embeds the directrix as a line, then $H=D+(e+1)F$, so for $m=e$, $h^0(\Sigma,\mathscr{O}(A-C))=h^0(\Sigma,\mathscr{O}(F))\geq 2$, as we can pull back from $h^{0}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathscr{O}(1))$.

Comment: Okay, I think I see why there exists an irreducible curve in $|C|$ now (hyperplane section), but I'm still confused about the second part.

Comment: The nef cone of a desingularization $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ of the normal surface $\Sigma$ is the convex cone spanned by the nef, basepoint free, nonample divisor classes of $F$ and of $D+eF$.  The ample cone of $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ consists of divisors linearly equivalent to $A=a(D+eF)+bF = aD + (b+ae)F$ for some choice of integers $a,b>0$.  The pullbacks of ample divisors on $\Sigma$ correspond to $a>0$ and $b\geq 0$.  In particular,  $ae+b-m$ is positive if $m<e$.  So, in this case, $h^0(\widetilde{\Sigma},\mathcal{O}(A-C)) = h^0(\widetilde{\Sigma},\mathcal{O}((a-1)D + (ae+b-m)F))$ is nonzero.